# Проблемы при разработке видеоплеера на основе FFMPEG и SDL

Tags: sdl, visual-c++, ffmpeg

Всем доброго времени суток!

Разрабатываю видеоплеер с помощью библиотек FFMPEG и SDL на 13 студии.

[Статья](http://habrahabr.ru/post/137793/) о том, как это все делать.

Все вроде бы хорошо, но...

**1 проблема:** отсутствие некоторых функций в `SDL.h`, таких как `SDL_SetVideoMode`, `SDL_CreateYUVOverlay`, `SDL_DisplayYUVOverlay`... Что-то об этом в этой статье не упоминается.

Но вроде как с горем пополам решил эту проблему: скачал SDL.dll и оттуда путем явного связывания и создания указателей на эти функции вытащил их адреса с помощью GetProcAddress. Есть другие варианты?

И тут возникла **2 проблема**: после компиляции запускается консоль, где красиво расписываются все параметры видео, затем появляется окно, в котором, по идее, я должен увидеть видео и похлопать в ладоши, но, кроме черного экрана, ничего я, собственно, не вижу. Причем 3-минутное видео отображается 10-секундным черным экраном, и программа завершает свою работу.

Может, кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой?
Или, может, есть рабочие исходники видеоплеера на студии?

Буду признателен любым ответам и советам!
Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Есть две версии SDL - первая и вторая. Во второй, например, нет функции SDL_SetVideoMode, вместо нее другая.

Я не знаю, как в Окнах, но в Linux есть SDL/sdl.h и SDL2/sdl.h
Тебе, как я понял, нужна первая версия библиотеки. Зайди на оф. сайт и скачай версию 1.3. Установи.

А при компиляции флаг должен быть -lSDL.

Comment: А поподробнее?
Да и в целом эта проблема то решена...криво, но решена.

Comment: а под винду?
Компилю в 13 студии под вин8

Comment: Ну, с флагом -lSDL.

Comment: поясните, что за флаг компиляции?

Comment: При компиляции, иногда компилятору указывают, какую библиотеку подключить. То есть при компиляции: g++ file.cpp -lSDL. А в студии где-то в настройках проекта есть пункт изменения флагов проекта. Где - не знаю. Я сижу на Linux